# AI is ignoring set parameters in Connect4

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently 90% done my C++ Connect4 game, but I'm running into a rather annoying error. The game plays fine, and everything works aside from one thing; the player plays against the computer, but the computer ignores the parameters I've set for it and places its piece anywhere on the board. Could this be an error in my logic? I know this isn't an example of AI but it's the best way to summarize it.
Here is the function:

```
void columnChoiceComputer(int computer)
{
int number = 0;
srand(time(0));
cout << (rand() % 6 + 1) << endl;
if (cin.fail())
{
    cout << "Error!";
    srand(time(0));
    cout << (rand() % 6 + 1) << endl;
}
while ((rand() % 6 + 1) > WIDTH || (rand() % 6 + 1) <= 0)
{
    cout << "Please select a different column.";
    srand(time(0));
    cout << (rand() % 6 + 1) << endl;
}
while (boardMatrix[(HEIGHT - 1) - number][((rand() % 6 + 1) - 1)] != 0)
{
    number++;
    if (number > (HEIGHT - 1))
    {
        cout << "Please select a different column.";
        srand(time(0));
        cout << (rand() % 6 + 1) << endl;
        number = 0;
    }
};


boardMatrix[(HEIGHT - 1) - number][(rand() % 6 + 1) - 1] = computer;
lastMoveY = (HEIGHT - 1) - number;
lastMoveX = ((rand() % 6 + 1)) - 1;
(system("cls"));
```

}

Comment: the core of your problem is that `rand()` gets a new number each call, so the step for updating the board with `(rand() % 6 + 1)` is completely different from all the other `(rand() % 6 + 1)`s that you were checking with, probably causing all kinds of confusion. your use of `srand()` is also likely problematic. you should include what your AI is supposed to be doing so someone can provide a more definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply kmdreko. The goal of the AI is to simply play connect4, it's playing the same way as the user in that it is selecting a column in which to drop a piece; however, I'm having it use a random number generator for numbers 1-6 instead of taking input from the keyboard like the user function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly a big thank you to those who helped me. The solution was very simple, instead of calling (rand() % 6 + 1) every time I would call the function, I merely had to set the first iteration of the random number to a variable called "computerChoice", and simply call that variable. Here is the updated code:

```
int number = 0;
srand(time(0));
int computerChoice = (rand() % 6 + 1);

while (computerChoice > WIDTH || computerChoice <= 0)
{
    cout << "Please select a different column.";
    srand(time(0));
    cout << (rand() % 6 + 1) << endl;
}
while (boardMatrix[(HEIGHT - 1) - number][(computerChoice - 1)] != 0)
{
    number++;
    if (number > (HEIGHT - 1))
    {
        cout << "Please select a different column.";
        srand(time(0));
        cout << (rand() % 6 + 1) << endl;
        number = 0;
    }
};

boardMatrix[(HEIGHT - 1) - number][computerChoice - 1] = computer;
lastMoveY = (HEIGHT - 1) - number;
lastMoveX = (computerChoice) - 1;
(system("cls"));
```